# How to wait until one of the multiple conditions becomes true in Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

In playwright is there a way for waiting until one of specified condition becomes true similar to one in webdriverio :

```js
      browser.waitUntil(
        () => this.twoFactorHeader.isExisting() === true || this.tosTitle.isExisting() === true || this.errorMessage.isExisting() === true || DashboardPage.consultBtn.isExisting() === true, {
          timeout: helper.defaultWaitTime(),
          timeoutMsg: `page is not loaded after ${helper.defaultWaitTime()} seconds`
        }
      )
```

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function